# How to redraw DataTable with new json data

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jquery datatable and I am stuck at loading the new data to datatable and redraw. I have the following code Snippet.

**First Time DataTable Initialization**

```
var myDataTable=$('#patient_data').DataTable({ 
                searching: false,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "process/get-patient-search.php",
                    "type": "POST",
                    data: {
                        "clinic": <?php echo $clinicID ?>
                    },
                    'dataSrc':function (data){
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "detail_id" },
                    { "data": "fname" },
                    { "data": "surname" },
                    { "data": "dentist" ,
                        "className":"hidden-xs"
                    },
                    { "data": "clinic_name" ,
                        "className":"hidden-xs"
                    },
                    { "data": "speciality" ,
                        "className":"hidden-xs"
                    },
                    { "data": "date_registered" ,
                        "className":"hidden-xs",
                    },
                    { "data": "detail_id" }
                ],
                "aoColumnDefs": [{
                    "aTargets": [7],
                     'searchable': false,
                     'orderable': false,
                     'className':'center',
                     'mRender': function (data, type, full, meta){
                         return '<button id="' + data+ '" onClick="getMoreInfo('+data+');" class="moreInfo"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>';
                     }
                }]

            });<br>
```

**Initial Response From Server**

```
[{"detail_id":"1",
  "fname":"Hakim",
  "surname":"Ali",
  "dentist":"Ariya Stark",
  "clinic_name":"Doctor ",
  "speciality":"O",
  "date_registered":"13\/02\/16"
 },
 {"detail_id":"2",
  "fname":"Maria",
  "surname":"Arshad",
  "dentist":"Ariya Stark",
  "clinic_name":"Doctor ",
  "speciality":"O",
  "date_registered":"13\/02\/16"
 }]
```

It works fine for the first. but I need to fetch the new data based on the user query search. And When I redraw the table It says that the

> DataTables warning: table id=patient_data - Requested unknown parameter 'detail_id' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

**My Redraw Code Snippet**

```
$("#search_submit").on('click',function(){
                if (search_patient.valid()) {
                    $('.errorHandler').fadeOut();
                    $.post('process/process-patient-search.php',$('#patient-search-form').serialize(), function(response){
                        if(isJson(response)){//isJson(response)
                            alert("data is json");
                            alert(response);
                            /* myDataTable.clear();
                            myDataTable.rows.add(response);
                            myDataTable.draw(); */
                            myDataTable.clear().draw();
                            myDataTable.rows.add(response); // Add new data
                            myDataTable.columns.adjust().draw();
                        }else{
                            alert(response);
                            /* 
                            $('.errorHandler').html('');
                            $('.errorHandler').html(response);
                            $('.errorHandler').fadeIn("slow");
                            $('.errorHandler').fadeOut(2000); */
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //alert('form is not valid');
                }

            });
            function isJson(str) {
                try {
                    JSON.parse(str);
                } catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

**Server Response**

```
[{"detail_id":"66",
 "fname":"Waseem",
 "surname":"Akram",
 "dentist":"Ariya Stark",
 "status":"1",
 "clinic_name":"Doctor ",
 "speciality":"S",
 "date_registered":"15\/09\/16"
},
{"detail_id":"67",
 "fname":"Waseem",
 "surname":"Akram",
 "dentist":"Ariya Stark",
 "status":"1",
 "clinic_name":"Doctor ",
 "speciality":"S",
 "date_registered":"15\/09\/16"
},
{"detail_id":"69",
 "fname":"Waseem",
 "surname":"Akram",
 "dentist":"Ariya Stark",
 "status":"1",
 "clinic_name":"Doctor ",
 "speciality":"S",
 "date_registered":"15\/09\/16"
 }]
```

I know that this question has already been asked and I have been searching all the day but none of the answer solved my problem. I tried every forum including the stack over flow and datatable forum.
I went through all the question and searched every possible answer and tried every thing but nothing solved my problem. I really need help with this. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Is this serverside? I assume so, but you don't have `"serverSide": true` in the initialisation code.  Also, you're not using the API to search, you're making a separate ajax call and trying to populate the datatable.  This is undoubtedly where you're going wrong.

Comment: I think the initial data format and the later one are different. Please add the initial data fed to the datatable

Comment: Dear Markpsmith I am populating the datatable with new data that's not from the server side I have configured the datatable on client side and only need to insert the new data. The reponse from the server is given in question the problem raises in the data repopulation. It says the warning that is provided in the question. The data is in json format and every thing should be fine with it. but don't know that what's wrong. It's simply insert the new data in data table there is no server side processing.

Comment: Hi, Sir I have now edited the question and also added the initial response from the server that is working correct. but the new response doesn't work it' says the warning above mentioned.

Comment: First, your function `isJson` is to string, if you want use `myDataTable.rows.add(response)`, you should convert your string in JSON object. I think that's your mistake ... check https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/102/

Comment: Dear sir If you see the data definition it's in json format returned from the server and I have also parsed it into json with isJSON() function. the function definition is given in the question post.

Comment: We can also see that the both (the initial response and the former response) are same and there is nothing changed. :)

Comment: Thanks CMedina I think it's working Now just added<br> myDataTable.clear();   myDataTable.rows.add(JSON.parse(response));
myDataTable.draw();

Comment: ok I understand, I can write my answer? and wait for your approval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself. 
**Revised DataTable Redraw Code Snippet**

```
$("#search_submit").on('click',function(){
                if (search_patient.valid()) {
                    $('.errorHandler').fadeOut();

                    $.post('process/process-patient-search.php',$('#patient-search-form').serialize(), function(response){

                        if(isJson(response)){//isJson(response)

                            myDataTable.clear();
                            myDataTable.rows.add(JSON.parse(response));
                            myDataTable.draw(); 

                        }else{

                            $('.errorHandler').html('');
                            $('.errorHandler').html(response);
                            $('.errorHandler').fadeIn("slow");
                            $('.errorHandler').fadeOut(2000);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //alert('form is not valid');
                }

            });
            function isJson(str) {
                try {
                    JSON.parse(str);
                } catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```